# Dual of Elvis: do this if not null?

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin has the Elvis operator to say 'get X, or if it's null, this alternative instead'.

What's the most concise, idiomatic way to say 'get X, and if it's not null, go ahead and do this with it'?

I'm thinking maybe the safe call operator `?.` combined with one of the scope functions: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html

But if that is so, then which of the five scope functions would it be correct and idiomatic to use here? Or is there an alternative I am missing?

Comment: Usually let and run will do so. Let is for taking the expression as parameter `it` and run will take it as `this` variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`let` is the usual choice here:

```kotlin
(some expression)?.let { 
    println(it) 
}
```